# QUdpSocket readyRead() not emmited?

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt and debugging an application that uses QtUdpSocket to receive some data.
it seems, that the readyRead() signal is never emitted:

```
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include<qdatastream.h>
#include "Globals.h"

typedef struct _udp_data_frame
{
    quint8 signal;
    quint8 rampNumber;
    QByteArray recvBuffer;
    quint32 payloadPacketSize;
}UDPDataFrame_t;

class MyUDP : public QUdpSocket
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyUDP(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool bindPorts(QHostAddress addr, qint16 port);
    void unbindPorts(void);
    void stopStreaming(void);

signals:
    void newMessage(const QString &from, const QString &message);
    void newData(const QString &from, UDPDataFrame_t data);

public slots:
    void readyRead(void);
    void messageReady(void);
    void sendMessage(QHostAddress hostAddress, quint16 hostPort, QString string);

private:
    QUdpSocket *socket_infoserver;
    QUdpSocket *socket_streamingclient;

    UDPDataFrame_t data;
    QByteArray buffer;
    QHostAddress clientAddr;
    quint16 clientPort;
    quint32 payloadPacketSize;
    quint8 header;
};
```

and

```
#include "myudp.h"
#include <iostream>

static inline quint32 ArrayToUInt(QByteArray source, QDataStream::ByteOrder byteOrder);
static inline quint8 ArrayToByte(QByteArray source);

static bool bStreamingStarted;

MyUDP::MyUDP(QObject *parent) : QUdpSocket(parent)
{
    socket_infoserver = new QUdpSocket();
    socket_streamingclient = new QUdpSocket();
}

bool MyUDP::bindPorts(QHostAddress addr, qint16 port)
{
    socket_infoserver->abort();
    socket_streamingclient->abort();

    QHostAddress remote_host;
    remote_host.setAddress("192.168.168.130");

    if (socket_streamingclient->bind(addr, ROPA_STREAMPORT))
    {
        socket_streamingclient->connectToHost(remote_host, ROPA_STREAMPORT);
        socket_streamingclient->waitForConnected(1000);
        connect(socket_streamingclient, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(messageReady()));
    }

    return true;
}

void MyUDP::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray temp_buffer;
    temp_buffer.resize(socket_infoserver->pendingDatagramSize());

    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;

    socket_infoserver->readDatagram(temp_buffer.data(), temp_buffer.size(),
                         &sender, &senderPort);

    emit newMessage(sender.toString(), temp_buffer);
}

void MyUDP::messageReady()
{
    ...
}
```

As for now I have confirmed that there are incoming packets using Wireshark. The destination IP and port are correct. Furthermore I can see the incoming data in command line using `nc -l -u -p <PORT>`. Also I have tried adding a `socket_streamingclient->hasPendingDatagrams()` right after binding, but there aren't any datagrams.

Is there an error in the code I am missing?
Or can you give hints on how to debug this issue?

I am happy to supply additional information or code if necessary.

Comment: Is your problem that `MyUDP::readyRead()` does not get called? Because the signal is connected to slot `MyUDP::messageReady()`, not `MyUDP::readyRead()`

Comment: No, my problem is, that messageReady(), which is (or should be) connected to the socket's readyRead() signal, is not called. The naming is bad, I know. Sorry for that.

Comment: I'd put the `connect` call for the signal earlier, maybe even in the constructor (as you only have to call it once, not each time you bind). As it is now, if the signal is emitted between connectToHost() and connect(), it could be lost

Comment: I tried shifting the connect() to between bind() and connectToHost(), but that doesn't help. I also tried calling hasPendingDatagrams() in a loop after binding, but it never returns true. Does that mean, that the socket actually doesn't receive the datagrams (and therefore doesn't emit the signal)?

Comment: `socket_streamingclient->waitForConnected(1000);` what does it return? It may fail.

Comment: It returns `true` immediately. (Although I don't understand what that function does in a UDP context.)

Comment: From quick look at the code, I do not know what is the problem with your code. But I suggest being "paranoid" about the success of your connections never trust them. I am uing this utility in my code which asserts uniqueness and success of the connection in debug mode: https://github.com/vladimir-kraus/qtutils/blob/main/qtutils/safeconnect.h And you should read about Qt5 style of connections, they are much more certain to succeed than ancient Qt4 style connections.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!
I replaced the connection
`connect(socket_streamingclient, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(MyUDP::messageReady()));`
by
`safeConnect(socket_streamingclient, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MyUDP::messageReady);`
The assertion is not called, so the connection should be fine right?
The slot (messageReady()), however, is still not reached.

Comment: It seems that the client socket was not `bind` correctly. Try this : `socket_streamingclient->bind(QHostAddress::Any, ROPA_STREAMPORT, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress |  QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint  )` and remove the connectToHost() and waitForConnect() - in UDP, the are no "stream" type as TCP.

Comment: That did the trick! Now the signal is emitted and the slot is reached. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested all suggested changes individually and it seems they are actually all necessary. The working version of `MyUDP::bindPorts()` now looks as follows:

```
bool MyUDP::bindPorts(QHostAddress addr, qint16 port)
{
    socket_streamingclient->abort();

    if(socket_streamingclient->bind( QHostAddress::Any, ROPA_STREAMPORT, 
                                     QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint) )
    {
        connect(socket_streamingclient, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MyUDP::messageReady);
    }

    return true;
}
```